# Добавить массив в таблицу MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, массивы

Подскажите как добавить такой массив в таблицу MySQL:

```
$arr = [
[
    "0" => 1, 
    "1" => "Иван",
    "2" => 10
],
[
    "0" => 2, 
    "1" => "Петр",
    "2" => 20
],
[
    "0" => 3, 
    "1" => "Василий",
    "2" => 30
]    
];
```

Вот так вроде должно добавляться, но не работает:

```
$inTable = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `Test` VALUES ('1', '$arr[0][0]', '$arr[1][1]', '$arr[1][2]')");
```

Comment: У тебя массив трехмерный, а ты вводишь как двухмерный.

Comment: И как правильно будет? Например в третью ячейку таблицы добавить "Петр"? В браузер все выводит "echo $arr[1][1]".

Comment: Зачем ты присваиваешь $mysqli->query...

Comment: И дай лучше весь код

Comment: Это весь код) только начинаю разбираться с таблицами. Вот надо этот массив запихнуть в таблицу, в цикле естественно) Но вот даже строку не получается туда засунуть. К базе данных все коннектится.

Comment: Не факт попробуй любое значение искусственно ввести в таблицу.

Comment: И выведи текст ошибки если он есть

Comment: Да если руками указать, например: $inTable = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `Test` VALUES ('1', '1', 'Петр', '20')"); то все ок добавляется. Может кавычки тут какие-то нужны

Comment: Сорри давно бэкендом не занимался и чушь всякую несу, $arr =  array(
[
    "0" => 1, 
    "1" => "Иван",
    "2" => 10
],
[
    "0" => 2, 
    "1" => "Петр",
    "2" => 20
],
[
    "0" => 3, 
    "1" => "Василий",
    "2" => 30
]    
);                 но это еще не все, ща быстро позырю

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr = [
    [
        "0" => "1", 
        "1" => "Иван",
        "2" => "10"
    ],
    [
        `"0" => "2", 
        "1" => "Петр",
        "2" => "20"
    ],
    [
        "0" => "3", 
        "1" => "Василий",
        "2" => "30"
    ]    
];
```

Comment: Столбцы можно не указывать)